# Url Mapping for a Web App built with Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

A Web App built with Google Apps Script has a Url link like this:

https://script.google.com/a/macros/mydomain.com/s/AKfy...iXUrQfobe6/exec

Any idea how to map such Url to a friendly one like:

app.myapp.mydomain.com

Comment: It doesn't really answer your request but it might be interesting to use the [url shortener api](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_urlshortener) not as friendly as you want but at least quite short ;)

Comment: aside from the app being built with GAS, how is this question related to Google Apps Script? (maybe I misunderstood what you are trying to do, but to me this sounds like a server administration question)

Comment: Slightly shorter - make a Google site, and use embed to get the script. I know that’s not quite what you’re looking for, but it was slightly better for my own case, since it was an intra company site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Web apps built with Google Apps Script cannot be served off of custom domains. You can create a redirect from your own domain, but the URL in the address bar must be script.google.com.

Comment: thanks Eric, I have done that already, it's good enough for my purpose

Comment: @erickoleda    Is there a reference for this statement? I wonder if that policy hasn't changed in the past five years.  thx.

Comment: No, still not possible.